# Flex, Java or AIR for local application

Tags: java, apache-flex, adobe

I don't know really well the diference between AIR and FLEX, i do with Java tought,

My question is that I want to build an application to run in local mode, but maybe in the future I want it to be available trought the web,

The basic sequence diagram is the following:

[image]

So I want the client to connect to a server for login information, and for storing some data, and I don't know wich one of the three technologies is the best..

Can you help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flex is a platform for creating client-side applications. AIR is a "wrapper" to run Flex applications on desktop instead in browser. It gives you some possibilities like access to local file system.

Use Flex for client side and decide if you want it to run in browser, like a web page, or install on desktop with AIR. Don't use Java for user interface if you can use Flex.

Use Java for server side application. You may be needing something like BlazeDS or GraniteDS for Flex-Java AMF communication.

Comment: Well on server side I just want a SQL Database and FileSystem to store the files, so I was thinking in not having any server side app, just in the destkop app use db connections and ftp upload or something like this, is this a good idea? or is better to have a server side app that handles all this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use FLEX technology.

because FLEX can create both AIR and WEB Application.
Currently you want to do desktop application that means run in local mode so better option is to use AIR application and then when you want to change to WEB than its also very useful to you and you can easily convert the Desktop Application into WEB Application.

Have a Nice Day...